# How do I send a JPEG file along with other data such as Strings and Integers from Android to a Server?

Tags: android, spring-boot

I have a JPEG file and some other data (of type String and Integer) that I'm trying to send from an Android activity to a a REST Controller on my Server (Spring).

How can I do so? There are so many libraries out there I'm not sure which is deprecated or not or what are some best practices...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One of the safest and fastest ways is using an MQTT server. It is not a simple solution, but the best for my programs:

- There is a good library on Android to send messages with pictures and other data.
- There are enough program languages that can connect to MQTT.
- Multiple Android devices can send data.
- Connection loss is solved by MQTT.
- Guarantee of delivering data: either in the same order or small chance on different order as sent by Android.
- It's secure.
- To improve security, I use base64 encoding, (also add sha256 checksums and dummy blocks with random data)
- For publishing on a website you need to program some backend part on the server.
- Most important: It's FREE

For details look:
https://mqtt.org/